# Filtering events by contract address and sender address

Tags: web3js, events, filters

I need to watch events by two parameters: address of token contract and sender address. I found how to watch contract address, but not sure how to watch also by sender address? Shoud I specify address to topics like this?:

```
var eventFilter = web3.eth.filter({
    fromBlock:0,
    toBlock: 'latest',
    address: '0xefcc9f9a5cb3d6062c18eeffdf90a29bb771fccc',
    'topics':[web3.sha3('Transfer(address,address,uint256,uint256)'), web3.sha3('0xdd7b798cbfe06af77fdc4b64e48f71672595adcf')]});
eventFilter.watch(function(error, result) {
    if(error) throw error;
    console.log(result);
});
```

or maybe there is a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The address in the FilterChange is the emitting contracts address.

You need to include the sender address in your event definition in order to get in FiltecChange. Only if you **index the address** it will show up in topics, so that you can filter for it.

```
event CalledTrigger (address indexed from, uint256 value1, uint256 value2);

function triggerEvent() public {
  uint256 myVal1 = 9999;
  uint256 myVal2 = 9999;
  emit CalledTrigger2(msg.sender, myVal1, myVal2);
}
```

But your problem might be that your topic[1] is the sha3 of an address, not the address I guess you want to filter for.